# Scroll to a position in Scrollviewer with normal scrollanimation

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, scrollview

I have a metro styled app with a scrollviewer. Now I would like to scroll to a position when the user clicks a button. I tried:

```
 MainScrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(x);
```

But then its "jumping" there quickly. I want to have a smooth animation up to x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API out of the box that would allow you to do that.
There is also no property that you could target with an animation.
You would need to either use frame-based animation (basically figure out where you are in the timeline and on each CompositionTarget.Rendering event - update the offset) or create an attached dependency property that calls ScrollToHorizontalOffset when its value changes and target that property with an animation.

Comment: You teased me since I always wanted to create these methods and it turns out harder than expected due to limitations in animating custom dependency properties. Check the [ScrollViewerExtensions](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/17803#328567) in the [WinRT XAML Toolkit](http://bit.ly/WinRTXamlToolkit).

Answer (score 0):

You could create a method that runs async and has a timer which increments the ScrollToHorizontalOffset(int x).

Say every 500ms it adds 10px.